# Some part of javascript code make chrome hang in Ios

Tags: javascript, ios, html, google-chrome

I am using some very simple html5 and js code to take photo by click of a button from mobile browser and send it to web service. This part of code works perfectly in Safari in Ios (Ipad). Also code works perfectly in Chrome browser Desktop and Desktop Mobile mode.

In Chrome browser on Ios;

- The part I take photo works (Take photo button) and takes photos and shows photo taken on input box no problem yet.
- When I click Save Photo button, the chrome browser hangs and does not
  respond.
- Unfortunately I do not have an Android device to test if this part of
  code works in Chrome in Android and can not debug Chrome on Ios.

This is the html part:

```
<tr id="photo-functions-row">
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <div style="max-width:30%">
      <label for="take-photo" class="custom-file-upload">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Take Photo
      </label>
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" id="take-photo" onchange="readURL(this);" />
      <button id="clear-photo" type="button" onclick="clearPhoto();" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" style="margin:5px;">Clear Photo</button>
      <button id="save-photo" type="button" onclick="savePhoto();" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" style="margin:5px;">Save Photo</button>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td> 
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is the js part:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#img-placeholder')
                .attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}


function savePhoto() {
    let files = document.getElementById("take-photo").files;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        let base64Image = e.target.result;
        console.log(base64Image);
        let params = [];
        let CalID = calItem.id;
        params[0] = CalID;
        params[1] = base64Image;
        sendPhoto(params);
    };
}



function sendPhoto(params) {
    var json = jQuery.post(savePhotoWebServiceAddress,
        {
            jsonData: JSON.stringify(params)
        }).done(function (data) {
            let photomessage = "";
            try {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if (obj != null) {
                    if (obj.success == true) {
                        photomessage = photoMessageSuccess;
                    }
                    else {
                        photomessage = photoMessageFailed;
                    }
                }             
            } catch (e) {
                photomessage = "An exception occured: " + e.message;
            }
            alert(photomessage);
            clearPhoto();
        });
}
```

There should be something specific breaking execution in Chrome browser on Ios.

Comment: What is the size of the image you are trying to save?

Comment: Inside Your `savePhoto()` put `reader.readAsDataURL` after `reader.onload` like You did inside `readURL()` and try again. BUT: my advice is to use the classic `FormData` and append the image to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, chrome on ios blocks alert messages and script execution stops when first alert is called. Removed alerts, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on the size of the image you're taking, what app you're taking it from, and what generation iPad you have. What kind do you have? It also depends on your CPU/RAM. Even if it's from the camera, the RAM takes a huge part in this. Also, Google could've accidentally created a bug that makes the iOS device hang. If anything, go check for updates for your iPad and iOS. Also, you can try to enable Page Refresh.